# Local file link to shared dropbox files

Tags: macos, hyperlink, dropbox, local

Since this is my first time posting a question on stackexchange, please excuse me if I've not included anything. Suggestions for a better post are very welcome!

**Background**

I'm looking for a way to create a `file://` link in e-mails with a specific purpose. In my company we're all using Macbooks with Outlook as our e-mail-client. As soon as a specific document is updated, I would like to be able to e-mail a colleague saying: "here is the  to the file". My personal link would be: `file:///Users/<MyUserName>/Dropbox/Filepath.ext`. However, this does not evaluate correctly on my colleagues computer. I have made it to work with a manual username change, but I'm hoping that there is a way to automatically fill in the username of that person.

**My Question:**

How can I make the link in such a way that it will always refer to that user's specific user folder?

**Resources explored**

I've tried working with `file://~/` but that always gives a 'can't find the document' error. I've tried googling it but Dropbox and other services only point towards URL-links or to their website. Stackexchange hasn't provided me with an answer so far ([Internal links / ":file//" links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742429/internal-links-file-links) is without answer). Searching for 'computer independent file links' haven't given me any solace either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what you want. You can check the dorpbox API and read a bit about it. But an easier way might be IFTTT, a free tool which launch triggers. So basically you need to create a folder in dropbox for each user and then use this tool to make triggers for each user. You can send an email and include the new dropbox link and as well you can program the IFTTT to send a file://Users//Dropbox/USER_DROPBOX_FOLDER/{{FILENAME}} whenever a file is placed in his folder.

Comment: That's an interesting suggestions, thanks! However, I don't think that will  work. Either because I don't want to force IFTTT on my colleagues, but also because it involves more work. A bit more of specification is in order; we have a bunch of client folders and files that are the same for every colleague. So this would mean linking to an existing file within an existing structure (e.g.   `~/Client X / Project 2 / Presentation.pptx`. But making the `file://` link work requires the proper username to be filled in, is there anyway to make a soft link that resolves once the user clicks on it?